# Is there a way to hook my computer speakers up to my tv?

Tags: speakers

There is probably some cable to do this?

Comment: You mean [like this](http://xkcd.com/841/)? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers is yes.

Unfortunately, we can't be very helpful, because you provided us with no information at all on the type of speaker connection at TV side and at computer side. It would be best to post some pictures, if you can.

The most popular connector for computer speakers is the [tip, ring, sleeve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tip_ring_sleeve) connector. Usually, the 3.5 mm version is used.

Also used is [TOSlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOSlink) connector for digital optical connection. There is also the [Mini-TOSlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOSlink#Mini-TOSLINK.C2.AE) version which looks like 3.5 mm TRS connector, but is optical. [Here's](http://www.moregadgets.ca/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=307) an image.

Another option is digital 3.5 mm TRS connector.

On the TV side, you could have [RCA connectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_connector), or TRS connector or TOSlink connector or Mini-TOSlink connector. You could also have a SCART connector for which you'd need to use adapter.

Most adapter names are simple. Just X to Y adapter. For digital electric and optical adapters, it's going to be a bit more complicated and if your speakers don't support optical connection or electric(sometimes called coaxial), there's probably nothing you can do.

Another potential problem is how TV sends its signal. Most TVs I've seen have headphone 3.5 MM TRS jack which can be used to connect speakers, but if it doesn't you'd have to check its setting on how to send audio through outputs.

Also, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_and_video_connector)'s a nice article about different connectors.